Why do I get {"status":"failure"} when using an info statement after getting a record from a custom module?
I started creating a script to perform certain automation inside a CRM.
The record I want to pull is within a user created "Policies" module.
whenever I use the get function and info the variable assigned to it I get a return of {"status":"failure"} but the script does not give me an error.
This issue, however, only occurs when getting any records from the Policies module. I can get any record from the Leads and the Deals modules and it returns the record info as expected.
Some things I have tried to debug this issue include:

Using a different browser
restarting my machine
checking and double checking that the module API name is correct (it is "Policies")
trying different records in the module to see if it is a specific record (no change)
running the script in a complete different instance of Zoho CRM (I work on 4) which also has a "Policies" module (and it works with no issues) which means its something in this ZohoOne instance.
checking my connection's Scopes to make sure its not an auth issue. (here are my current scopes: ZohoCRM.modules.ALL, ZohoCRM.Files.CREATE, ZohoCRM.Files.READ).

I am truly hoping I'm making a stupid mistake and its easily fixable as I need to get work done.
void automation.Test(Int policyid, int dealid, int leadid)
{
    policy = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Policies",policyid);
    info policy;

    deal = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Deals",dealid);
    info deal;

    lead = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Leads", leadid);
    info lead; 
} 

the above code is the test script I set up to show what's happening.
I should expect to see 3 info statements in the console displaying the 3 json maps containing the record fields and the data connected to them.
instead I see the first statement as {"status":"failure"} and the last two returning the data as expected.
the attached image excludes the info for the leads and deals records for prifacy purposes but they are there and working.

After doing some more extensive digging i realized that my mistake was in fact silly. the record ID i was testing with was invalid as i was using the Canvas ID instead of the Record ID (see URL Below). the canvas ID is appended at the end of the URL not Record ID.
"https://one.zoho.com/zohoone/taxisure/home/cxapp/crm/org816608683/tab/CustomModule1/5835662000022212001/canvas/5835662000001527001"

invalid Record ID was used, make sure to use the right Record ID found in the URL when viewing the record.
